# WSO2 BPS 3.5.0 and Activiti REST API

Tags: activiti, wso2-business-process

I'm working on a proyect that uses some products of WSO2 like API Manager, ESB and BPS. The issue that I can't solve is, how can I access the Activiti services like **identity/groups** or **identity/users** through BPS?.

I downloaded, installed  and ran BPS on my notebook. Enter to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9445/carbon and load one of the samples files: *CreditApprovalProcess.bar*. After that I created some users and roles. I've tried with *postman* to hit these URLS from the [docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/BPMN+REST+API):

- /repository/tasks --> http://...:9445/bpmn/repository/tasks
- /repository/deployments --> http://...:9445/bpmn/repository/deployments
- /repository/process-definitions --> http://...:9445/bpmn/repository/process-definitions

and they all work fine. However when I tried to hit these services:

- /identity/groups --> http://...:9445/bpmn/identity/groups
- /identity/users --> http://...:9445/bpmn/identity/users

defined [here](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_get_a_list_of_users) , I got this response `{"errorMessage":"The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request","statusCode":500}` . I've read that BPS 3.5.0 integrates Activiti engine and thus those services were available but clearly I'm doing something wrong. I'm new in WSO2 and I have to learn a lot yet so I appreciate any suggestion/idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Activiti BPMN engine is integrated into WSO2 BPS and it is using WSO2 Carbon Kernel based user management. Hence /identity/* Rest APIs, will not work in WSO2 BPS engine.

If you want to retrieve user/group information, use UserAdmin soap service. Following link will explain how you can do it in API Manager product, but instructions are similar for BPS as well.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM160/Calling+Admin+Services+from+Apps

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hasitha ! I was expecting to access the Activiti services as stated in the docs, but it's not possible. I follow the instructions from the Link  you've provided (I modified the carbon.xml from BPS) but I couldn't create a SOAP endpoint from the API Manager using this "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9445/services/UserAdmin?wsdl". It says "Please use a valid wsdl endpoint". I test the link in the browser and I can see the XML. Do you have any ideas?